# Accept type is invalid , INVALID_ACCEPT_TYPE.GMP_ITEM_QUERY_API ( Walmart ItemSearch API Error )

Tags: api, walmart-api, http-accept-header

Searching Item from Walmart Catalog Error 406 Not Acceptable
"code": "INVALID_ACCEPT_TYPE.GMP_ITEM_QUERY_API"
"info": "Accept type is invalid."

The Walmart Item Search API allows us to query the Walmart.com global product catalog by item keyword, UPC or GTIN.

API CALL

> GET https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/items/walmart/search?query=ipad
> WM_SVC.NAME: 4PSite
> WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: {{$guid}}
> Authorization: Basic NDdmNzA4MY0LdfgfgdfghMThlNDQwOkRQZFRRYTdpZ3GDFGDFRFDGDFGETmRsVEZPOHZPRCYUw0RHRXM296VGlsVXFaZFZmTHpTdVNsdfdsafadfgesgdfg0....
> WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN: eyJraWQiOiI3NGU2ODE4Mi1iMzJkLTQ4ZDEtYThjOS03YjMyNDljMTk1NmQiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiZGlyIn0..EzxhCQ9QIKhWMvdI._uvEAJGZtvfjX7AbwGd.....

API CALL ERROR

```
"error": [
    {
        "code": "INVALID_ACCEPT_TYPE.GMP_ITEM_QUERY_API",
        "info": "Accept type is invalid.",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "category": "DATA",
        "causes": [],
        "identify": {
            "entry": []
        }
    }
```

Need help...

[Image: Error Result of Postman call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1Kcd.png)

Comment: I believe the API is expecting the "Accept" header and try using "application/json" as the value.

Comment: worked thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, try adding the header "Accept" as "application/json" and it should work.

For more context, it is a GET call and "Accept" is more relevant than the Content-Type which is mostly associated with POST/PUT calls that take body as well.

Comment: Thank You Soooooooo much brother